# How to tell if my node is online (conflicting information)

Tags: network, full-node

I am really confused. I am attempting to set up a listening node. When I look at bitnodes.earn.com it shows my node as `offline` when searching by IP, but when I run `getconnectioncount` it returns a positive number and getnetworkinfo returns

```
{
  "version": 190001,
  "subversion": "/Satoshi:0.19.0.1/",
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "localservices": "0000000000000409",
  "localservicesnames": [
  "NETWORK",
    "WITNESS",
    "NETWORK_LIMITED"
  ],
  "localrelay": true,
  "timeoffset": -13,
  "networkactive": true,
  "connections": 20,
  "networks": [
    {
      "name": "ipv4",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "ipv6",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "onion",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    }
  ],
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "incrementalfee": 0.00001000,
  "localaddresses": [
  ],
  "warnings": ""
}
```

What is going on? How can I tell if my node is actually accepting connections? Is this because I am still downloading the chain? All I am looking for it to rebroadcast/relay my transactions.

Comment: The `"reachable": true` config in both ipv4 and ipv6, as well as the >8 connection count leads me to believe you are indeed connected and port 8333 is open.

Comment: any idea why bitnodes.earn.com would say my node is unreachable?

Comment: Bitnodes crawls the network hopping from node-to-node in order to paint a description of the network as a whole. The process in which Bitnodes uses is specific to their service, perhaps you could try reaching out to Bitnodes to see what the issue is. From a bitcoin core standpoint, you are receiving both inbound and outbound connections.